# Seeing Junk codes in Eclipse console when trying to execute REST Assured Framework in Cucumber

Tags: eclipse, automation, cucumber, rest-assured

I can see my codes executing and **also can see the execution flow in the server**. However, I am facing an issue with **junk codes that I am able to see in Eclipse's console** along with the output which is I require.

I am not able to add the junk code as it exceeds the character limits.

Comment: Do you mean the ANSI color codes? Try tunning with `--monochrome` (or monochrome = true, if you are using a JUnit runner with @CucumberOptions)

Comment: My system's IP had changed because of which I was seeing that error. It is working fine now. Thanks for the help..